# Organize a list based on a given element of that list

Tags: list-manipulation

If I have these three lists:

```
list1={{0.01,87.,0.},{0.03,87.,0.18353},{0.1,87.,0.494987},{0.3,87.,0.899803},{1.,87.,1.08076},{3.,87.,1.10593},{10.,87.,1.04781},{10.,87.,1.02449},{10.,87.,0.964193},{30.,87.,1.0602},{30.,87.,1.04075},{30.,87.,1.05987},{100.,87.,1.14661},{100.,87.,1.00639},{100.,87.,1.09384},{300.,87.,1.067},{300.,87.,1.15047},{300.,87.,1.10715},{1000.,87.,1.05152},{1000.,87.,1.06942},{1000.,87.,1.17143},{3000.,87.,1.12162},{10000.,87.,1.13136}}

list2={{0.01,75.,0.},{0.03,75.,0.},{0.1,75.,0.0959691},{0.3,75.,0.37954},{1.,75.,0.678807},{3.,75.,0.90385},{10.,75.,0.965262},{10.,75.,1.01025},{10.,75.,1.01675},{30.,75.,1.04836},{30.,75.,1.11345},{30.,75.,1.09146},{100.,75.,1.16961},{100.,75.,1.19018},{100.,75.,1.16968},{300.,75.,1.20834},{300.,75.,1.22955},{300.,75.,1.19569},{1000.,75.,1.25479},{1000.,75.,1.32295},{1000.,75.,1.22151},{3000.,75.,1.28794},{10000.,75.,1.25897}}

list3={{0.01,55.,0.},{0.03,55.,0.},{0.1,55.,0.},{0.3,55.,0.},{1.,55.,0.},{3.,55.,0.},{10.,55.,0.},{10.,55.,0.},{10.,55.,0.},{30.,55.,0.},{30.,55.,0.},{30.,55.,0.},{100.,55.,0.},{100.,55.,0.},{100.,55.,0.},{300.,55.,0.0721335},{1000.,55.,0.214175},{3000.,55.,0.748622},{10000.,55.,1.05191}}
```

How can I make the list to combine such as they get organized from smallest to highest number based on the first element of the list (which go from 0.01 to 10.000) as to get `{0.01,87,0,0.01,75,0,0.01,55,0,.......10000.,87.,1.13136,10000.,75.,1.25897,10000.,55.,1.05191}`

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Flatten @ SortBy[{First}] @ Join[list1, list2, list3]
```

> ```
> {0.01,87.,0.,0.01,75.,0.,0.01,55.,0.,0.03,87.,0.18353,0.03,75.,0.,0.03,55., 0.,
>  0.1, 87.,0.494987,0.1,75.,0.0959691,0.1,55.,0.,0.3,87.,0.899803,0.3,75.,0.37954,0.3,55., 0., 
>  1., 87.,1.08076,1.,75.,0.678807,1.,55.,0.,3.,87.,1.10593,3.,75.,0.90385,3.,55.,0., 
>  10., 87.,1.04781,10.,87.,1.02449,10.,87.,0.964193,10.,75.,0.965262,10.,75.,1.01025, 
>  10., 75., 1.01675,10.,55.,0.,10.,55.,0.,10.,55.,0.,30.,87.,1.0602,30.,87.,1.04075, 
>  30., 87., 1.05987,30.,75.,1.04836,30.,75.,1.11345,30.,75.,1.09146,30.,55.,0.,30.,55.,0., 
>  30., 55., 0.,100.,87.,1.14661,100.,87.,1.00639,100.,87.,1.09384,100.,75.,1.16961, 
>  100., 75., 1.19018,100.,75.,1.16968,100.,55.,0.,100.,55.,0.,100.,55.,0.,300.,87.,1.067, 
>  300., 87., 1.15047,300.,87.,1.10715,300.,75.,1.20834,300.,75.,1.22955,300.,75.,1.19569, 
>  300., 55., 0.0721335,1000.,87.,1.05152,1000.,87.,1.06942,1000.,87.,1.17143,
>  1000., 75., 1.25479,1000.,75.,1.32295,1000.,75.,1.22151,1000.,55.,0.214175,
>  3000., 87., 1.12162,3000.,75.,1.28794,3000.,55.,0.748622,10000.,87.,1.13136,
>  10000., 75., 1.25897,10000.,55.,1.05191}
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works great! I really appreciate it

Comment: @John, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Comment: If I wanted to implement your code for another list but using Flatten at level 1 or 2, what would be the notation for that?. I tried  `Flatten @ SortBy[{First}] @ Join[list1, list2, list3],1` , `Flatten @ SortBy[{First}] @ Join[list1, list2, list3,1]` etc.. but of course they are not correct.

Comment: @John, you can use `Flatten[SortBy[{First}] @ Join[list1, list2, list3],1]` or `Flatten[#,1]&@SortBy[{First}] @ Join[list1, list2, list3]`.

Comment: kglr Thank you so much for your help! It works great!

Answer (score 0):

From the description that you give, this what you want:

```
listtotal = Sort[Join[list1, list2, list3], #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &]
```

Even

```
listtotal = 
 Sort[Join[list1, list2, list3], #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &] // Flatten
```

if you want the list flattened.

This, however, does not return your desired output. But in your output, the numbers are not ordered...